# Android ActionBar isn't created

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm currently working on a mp3 library on Android. Thing is, there are 4 tab, representing Songs, Albums, Artists and Playlists. My main activity creates a tabspec for each tab and add them to a tabhost.
The problem is, I can't use the ActionBar. I tried the tutorial from Android Developpers and it works fine, however when I try to apply it on my project it doesn't work. I can't see the actionbar and if I try a getActionBar() in my activity it returns null.

As in the tutorial I put this code in the activity :

```
@Override    
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And I created this menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:title="Hello !"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I suppose there are more things to do in order to display the actionbar, yet I can't find an accurate on the Web since now ... Does this have something to do with the xml from my main activity ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: The action bar is only available from Android 3.0 and above, and you need to set your application theme to Holo.

Comment: I put this in the manifest :
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

Comment: And what about the application `theme`?

Comment: I put the theme to Holo and it does work :) Thank you very much K-Ballo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action bar is only available from Android 3.0 and above, and you need to set your application theme to Holo.

Besides setting the sdk version, for instance:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

You also have to make the application theme use *Holo*.

Comment: For me, still no action bar... :(
Menu button brings it up from the bottom, but no action bar.

Answer (score 5):

For me I added this to my manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Hopefully that saves some time from having to look it up.

Comment: What version are you on? I think they may have changed it recently

Comment: AS 1.2, target api 19 min 14.

Answer (score 0):

make `android:minSdkVersion="14"` it works for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer to a 5 year old question with answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.